# Unable to Rename Image name which capture by camera of intel xdk

Tags: cordova, camera

I am working on intel xdk cordova.But I am unable to capture image or after that i want to rename it. and save into specify path of mobile directory. it redirect by name of "test.jpg" every time

```html
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.add",onSuccessCam); document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.busy",onSuccessCam); document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.camera.picture.cancel",onSuccessCam); function capturePhoto() { intel.xdk.camera.takePicture(50,false,"jpg");}
function onSuccessCam(evt) { if (evt.success == true){ var image = document.createElement('img'+img_count); image.src=intel.xdk.camera.getPictureURL(evt.filename); image.id=evt.filename; } 
}
```

Comment: `var image = document.createElement('img'+img_count)` this is not creating your file name. Its element name. which mean tag name (`<img/>`)

Comment: This is not part of logic actually I want capture it. and rename it.

Comment: Sorry i could not find solution for your issue. But i can say that `var image = document.createElement('img')` is to create element in HTML. `var image = document.createElement('img'+img_count)` will create HTML element like this `<img1>`,`<img2>`,`<img3>`....`<imgn>`.

Comment: Thank for your interest. Can you give me simple example for Capturing picture using intel xdk and give this picture name is in datetime format

Comment: I am sorry to say this. I have no idea on intel xdk plugin. But i have idea on simple cam plugins like this [https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera)